# LEFT OUTER JOIN in Hibernate Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, hibernate-criteria

I have below classes

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
 Class A{
 private long a_id;
 private C C;

 }

 Class B extends A{
 private D d;
 }

 Class C{
 private long c_id;
 }

 Class D{
 private long d_id;
 private Set<B> bs;
 }
```

Here class B is extends Class A. Trying to query as below

```
Criterion criterion = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq(
                    "b.c", c_instance));

 Criteria c = session.createCriteria(D.class, "d")
 c.createAlias("bs", "b",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,criterion);
 c.createAlias("bs.c","c")
```

**Output Query:**

```
select d.d_id from D d left outer join B bs on d.d_id=bs.d_id and bs.c_id=2489 inner join A on bs.a_id=A.a_id inner join C A.c_id=C.c_id
```

Im getting an error as c_id is unknonwn column in B. Though the table B doesn't have the column c_id its parent table has. How can I write an query to achive left outer join here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess bs is a set of Class B and you are trying to fetch c.createAlias("bs.c","c")  from class B, Which is not there

Comment: Yes, c is not a property of class B, But it can inherit from Class A which doesn't happen. Thats my question